# A number of services registering in another service that has no dependencies to them? (lazy-loading)

Tags: angularjs, lazy-loading, lazy-initialization, angularjs-service

I want to have a servcie called `FeatureRegistry` with whom all features are registering. The registering features have a dependency on the FeatureRegistry (and not vice versa).

How i did it right now was:

```
angular.module('app').factory('FeatureRegistry', function(){
  var FeatureRegistry = new Object();
  FeatureRegistry.features = new Array(); 
  FeatureRegistry.registerFeature = function(feature){
    FeatureRegistry.features.push(feature);
  }
  return FeatureRegistry;
}

angular.module('app').factory('Feature', function(FeatureRegistry){
  var Feature = new Object();
  FeatureRegistry.registerFeature(Feature);
  return Feature;
}
```

But the feature never seems to register.
If I look up in the FeatureRegistry in features.

I tested it with a FeatureController:

```
angular.module('app').controller('FeatureController', 
  function($scope, FeatureRegistry){
  $scope.features = FeatureRegistry.features;
  return this; // not sure if a return is necessary
}
```

---

**EDIT:**
So now I know that services are lazy loaded and only instantiated when they are injected. But that is counter-intuitive with the application I want to achieve, because the features are supposed to be in there separate files and folders and I don't want to change the dependencies of `FeatureRegistry` anytime a new feature gets added.

---

EDIT 2:

Now I made a diagram to show how the structure should look:
[image]

Comment: Your `FeatureRegistry` factory needs to return object `FeatureRegistry`.

Comment: ups, yeah, forgot to type that... but that's not the error^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to inject `Feature` somewhere, otherwise it won't be instantiated.  E.g.,

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, FeatureRegistry, Feature) {
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tSq22c3mBtQLxLbI0bVh?p=preview)

Comment: is there a function to instantiate it without injecting it somewhere?

Comment: Because i would like to have many 'feature' implemented in there own files, and don't want to always add another injection into `MainCtrl` for this example.. but rather have an instantiation done in the file were I'm defining it. 
I'm using require.js to load all modules... and don't want to touch the FeatureRegistry's, dependencies everytime I implement and add another feature.

Comment: You could use the `$injector`.  E.g., `app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, FeatureRegistry, $injector) { $injector.get('Feature')`.  I'm not sure if that will work if you are loading your `Feature` service later though.